# fill in missing data based on a two column match

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset, and the first three variables in the dataset look like so:

```
id <- c(I-0009,I-0009,I-0009,I-0009,I-0009)
occasion<- c(1,1,2,2,3) 
time < - c(37800, NA, 54000, NA, 61200)
```

The actual dataset is longer with thousands of IDs and more variables. There is randomly missing data randomly on time. Is there a way to impute the missing time values. If ID and occasion match then I want to impute time that also matches. So for this truncated example, the soultion would be:

```
id <- c(I-0009,I-0009,I-0009,I-0009,I-0009)
occasion<- c(1,1,2,2,3) 
time < - c(37800, 37800, 54000, 54000, 61200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(id = c("I-0009","I-0009","I-0009","I-0009","I-0009"),
                 occasion = c(1,1,2,2,3), 
                 time = c(37800, NA, 54000, NA, 61200))
df %>% 
    group_by(id, occasion) %>% 
    tidyr::fill(time, .direction = "down")
```

Caveat: before imputing you need to make sure that `time` is unique to each id-occasion group. Also, if depending on the location of `NA` values you might need to change the `.direction` argument within `fill` function.